# How can I put a class as a element parameter in react router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/nav" element={Nav()}/>
            <Route path="/page1" element={Page1()}/>
            <Route path="/page2" element={Page2()}/>
            <Route path="/map" element={Mapp()}/>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The above is my function, which I render. nav, page1, and page2 all work fine since I wrote them as functions. However, the "Mapp" is a class. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component's `element` prop takes a ReactElement, i.e JSX. I suspect the `Nav`, `Page`, and `Page2` function components work because they take no props and return JSX. If these are actually React components they should be passed as JSX. Same goes for class-based components, pass them as JSX.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/nav" element={<Nav />}/>
        <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />}/>
        <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />}/>
        <Route path="/map" element={<Mapp />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```